# CancelEdit does not keep focus on edited cell in DataGridView c#

Tags: c#, datagridview

When I enter some value in a cell in DataGridView and click on another cell the cellvalidating event handler code is executed. Even if validation fills, the cell on which I click gets highlighted. My requirement is that the cell should remain selected and cursor should blink in the cell for editing after removing the invalid value. Am using the below code if the validation fails:

```
DataGridView1.CancelEdit();
```

I have tried adding

```
DataGridView1.CurrentCell.Selected = true;
DataGridView1.BeginEdit(true);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `e.Cancel = true` like below.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
{
    int i;

    if (!int.TryParse(e.FormattedValue.ToString(), out i))
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        MessageBox.Show("Please input a integral number.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I changed my code with the above solution a bit and it worked:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridView1.CancelEdit();
    e.Cancel = true;
    DataGridView.BeginEdit(true);
}
```