# How to format background of DataGridView exported to Excel?

Tags: c#, excel, winforms

I want to format the background of my header cells in excel, which is populated trhough my Datagridview. I´ve tried it with

`ws.Cells[1. 2].Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid;`

`ws.Cells[1, 2].Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(Color.LightGray);`

but i got a error message which says the name ExcelFillStyle.Solid does not exist in the current context. Any ideas?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly **welcome** to the SO community as a **new contributor**!

Doing some research I would recommend changing the **header-color** of the **GridView** using something like this:

```
_dataGridView.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Blue;
_dataGridView.EnableHeadersVisualStyles = false;
```

This was found on **SO** here:
[SO - How to change the color of dataGridView header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247800/how-to-change-the-color-of-winform-datagridview-header)

However If you wanted to tackle this using a more custom approach where you can set **specific cells** (items) background colors, this can be done using using:

```
DataGridView1.CurrentCell = DataGridView1.Item("ColumnName", 5)

columnHeadingsRange.Interior.Color = XlRgbColor.rgbSkyBlue;
```

The use case for this is explained on **SO** here:

*[Focus-a-specific-cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4918904/datagridview-focus-a-specific-cell)*

[Cell-color-changing-in-excel-using-c-sharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2452417/cell-color-changing-in-excel-using-c-sharp)

Using these two sources should help you achieve what you need as these both have been **answered**.

Comment: I thought it would only work with ExcelFillStyle.Solid but it worked with columnHeadingsRange.Interior.Color = XlRgbColor.rgbSkyBlue; also. Thank you alot!